# How can i secure my aws s3 bucket to be write only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have s3 bucket where i will upload pdf files from my front end. The front end will have 'careers' page where everybody can apply for some work position and upload his CV. I am using aws sdk for that on my nodejs api. But the CV on the S3 bucket needs to be private of course. The problem is that SDK code upload works if the s3 bucket is maked public only.

For file upload i am using multer.

```
const upload = multer({
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
  storage: multerS3({
    acl: 'public-read',
    s3,
    bucket: bucket_name',
    key: function(req, file, cb) {       
      req.file = file.originalname;
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
  })
});
```

How can i make the uploaded cv secure on my s3 bucket ? So everyody can upload files on it, but it should be private and no one will not get access to it to READ.

Comment: The proper way to do this is for your backend to generate a pre-signed url and then let the frontend upload something to that url, the frontend then does not need any credentials and does in fact not even need to know that it is interacting with s3.

Comment: Can you send me some example/documentation how can be this done please ?

Comment: Google is your friend: e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SDK to gnerate a pre-signed url. Here is the JS example for this task.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascriptv3/example_code/s3/src/s3_put_presignedURL.ts

Comment: Thanks for your response. So using pre-signed url is secure for this use-cases ?

Comment: Correct - that is the basic reason why this functionality was implemented.

Comment: After my url is generated with the sdk code, and i paste in the browser what should happen ? because i get no suck key error ....

Comment: Look at the Java example. You can use the URL to upload an object. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GeneratePresignedUrlAndUploadObject.java